# Password Protect HTM files in SPSS?

Tags: html, password-protection, spss

I created an HTM web report file through the export function after selecting a descriptive statistic report in the output table of SPSS. I want to password protect these HTM files. I cannot see if this option is available through the software itself. Do I have to do this outside of the software on my own, or does SPSS have the ability to provide this protection for me?

Comment: ...I'm using the student version also...which is a sad minimalist edition of SPSS. I can't even make a table with this version. Kind of lame that they do this to what would be future customers.

Answer (score 0):

OUTPUT EXPORT does not provide password-protected encryption,so you would need to do this afterwards.  There is a web report output option including password protection, but it is designed for the Collaboration and Deployment Services system, so it would not be useful for most SPSS Statistics users, student or otherwise.

Comment: accept
Thanks...perhaps it is not even an issue if the file was made on my own personal server, and only transferred between school emails. The file is not "online" in any way...which I think was a preconceived notion that I had to dispel. It just spits it out to the server being used each time you open it...correct?